# Use of const pointer to class in function

Tags: c++, constants, shared-ptr

I am using std::shared_ptr liberally in my code. I have a few functions that I want to call from MyClass using "this" so have declared these functions as (for example)

```
int AnotherClass::foo(const MyClass *obj)
{
}
```

I want the const to make it clear obj is not going to get changed since I am passing a raw pointer. 
However inside foo I have

```
int AnotherClass::foo(const MyClass *obj)
{
    int number = obj->num_points()-1;
}
```

and my compiler is complaining that "the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function". num_points is a simple get function declared and defined in the header:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  ...
  int num_points(){return _points.size();}
  ...
private:
  std::vector<MyPoint> _points;
};
```

What's the best way around this? Obviously I can get rid of the const requirement in foo but I like the rigidity it imposes. 
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make that member function `const`:

```
int num_points() const // <---
{
    return _points.size();
}
```

This way you can call it on `const` objects. Get in the habbit to qualify like this every function that doesn't alter the object's state.

Answer (score 6):

Declare `num_points` as const, too:

```
int num_points() const
{
    return _points.size();
}
```